# jQuery UI resizable handle with an inner element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Im trying to place an inner div to my resizable handle, but it renders the handle useless.

```
<div class="layer" style="width: 150px;">
<div class="left ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w">
    <div><<< div</div>
</div>
<div class="right ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e">>>></div>
</div>
​
$('.layer').resizable({
    handles: null
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MatteS75/3dwVp/15/

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

changing the _mouseCapture method in the jquery ui resizable widget to this makes it work:

```
_mouseCapture: function(event) {
    var capture = false;
    for (var i in this.handles) {
        var handle = $(this.handles[i])[0];
        if (handle == event.target || $.contains(handle, event.target)) {
            capture = true;
        }
    }

    return !this.options.disabled && capture;
},
```

I also created a ticket and pull request for this:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8756